# Google Analytics bot blocking filter based on bounce rate, pages per session and average session duration

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, filtering, google-analytics-spam

I looked in Google Analytics to view my website traffic. Out of over 900 landing pages, nearly half look like bot traffic.

Here is what I am looking at:
Acquisition > All Traffic > Channels > Direct > Secondary Dimension dropdown: Network Domain

If I see: 
Bounce Rate = 100% + Pages/Session = 1.00 + Avg. Session Duration = 00:00:00
then to me that seems like a good indicator of bot traffic.

Any recommendations on what filters I should apply? There are too many Network Domains to block and I would rather use a different type of filter.

Can I create a single filter for the three elements I just mentioned?
(Bounce Rate = 100% + Pages/Session = 1.00 + Avg. Session Duration = 00:00:00)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check the "Bot filtering" option in Google Analytics. That will exclude all traffic generated by known bots and spiders.

[image]

After that you should start analyzing your data to **identify anomalies**. As you said, bot traffic typically has a 100% bounce and 1 page per session but it could be more traffic without value so you need to search for all inaccurate data. Each one that you detected should be transferred to a exclude filter for a new clean Analytics view.

At any time it can appear another bot that generates an anomaly in your data so you need to implement a **permanent process of reviewing** your data quality.

That way, you can maintain a **clean view with accurate data**.

Comment: I already had the "Bot Filtering" box selected. I was surprised to see half of the traffic with Bounce Rate = 100% + Pages/Session = 1.00 + Avg. Session Duration = 00:00:00.